# Rails, nested has_many association, finding all children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some nested models that look something like:

```
class Company
  has_many :managers
end

class Manager
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task
end
```

So that's all fine but what if I'm in the `Company` controller and I want to get all the `Task.ids` for all of the employees in that company? The big problem is that Mongoid doesn't have like `has_many :through => resource_name` like AR does so how can I avoid something ugly like:

```
@company = Company.find params[:id]

@company.managers.each do |manager|
  manager.employees.each do |employee|
    employee.tasks.each do |task|
      puts task.id
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps there's a Rails way to do this that I don't know, but you could just use some simple Ruby trickery:

```
puts @company.managers.map(&:employees).flatten.map(&:tasks).flatten.map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is long-since answered, but I came across the post and wanted to note that the following might be a slightly more compact solution:

`puts @company.managers.map(&:employees).flat_map(&:tasks).flat_map(&:id)`

Answer (score 1):

The above answers looks good, but if we try the same with joins would be faster in execution. Please take a look in the below code.

For all employees for a Company

```
@company = Company.find params[:id]
Employee.joins(manager: :company).where('manager.company_id=?', @company.id)
```

For all tasks for a Company

```
Task.joins(employee: [manager: :company]).where('manager.company_id=?', @company.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! One issue is that this method of parameterization can be unsafe if the input is not carefully sanitized and made safe for sql, ie insertion attacks.

Comment: I have edited the context on the suggestion of Silvashy,  hope it is better to use now.